# How long should the Repository Creation Utility take for Oracle Portal

Tags: oracle, webcenter

I'm running the Oracle Repository Creation Utility (RCU) as a precursor to installing WebCenter, and the schema creation process is stuck on the "Portal" step. The first 10-12 steps each took less than 30 seconds to complete, and the last step has been going for 2 hours 14 minutes.

I checked the rcu log files, and they are constantly being updated with new progress information as though the process is still working. I haven't been able to find anyone else on the internet with this problem. From various screenshots on google, it looks like it can complete in under 10 minutes in some cases.

[image]

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Been a long time since we instaled Portal, but it definitely didn't take this long.  I'd have a look around for the most recently modified log files and tail them to look for errors...

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but there are no errors in the log, and it is still being written to...

Comment: Scratch that, it just finished... 4 hours and 26 minutes! Wow. Could this be caused by being on a VM with only one CPU?

Comment: Dave tanks for sharing. I'm facing the same with RCU for ODI. It takes too much time, perhaps because the machine where the database is running is too slow!. 4 hours and 18 min and not yet done. Now I know that I don't have to stop the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

this is odd as I run this often and against a vm. It never takes longer than a few minutes. Versions are needed to help further.